# JavaScript - Count how many time a button is pressed(function)

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick

I'm trying to count how many times a button is pressed, however I dont think this is right, because the count button keeps incrementing even if the 'Saying Hello' button isn't clicked

Any thoughts?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>JSExample</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function hello() {
               alert("Hello there!");
            }

            var countClicks = 0;

            function upCount() { 

                if(document.getElementById('hello').onclick = "hello()") {
                    countClicks++;
                    alert(countClicks);
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }

            }

        </script>

        <p><input type="button" name="button" value="Saying Hello" id="hello" onclick="hello();"/></p>

        <p><input type="button" name="click" value="Counting" id="click" onclick="upCount();"/></p>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Y, i don't exactly understand your problem. Right now on click 'Saying hello' you are calling a function 'hello()' which only pops up an alert with 'Hello there'. On clicking 'Counting' button, you are checking a very strange condition that i don't exactly understand and then increment the value. So, if you want to count how many times 'say hello' was clicked, and then present it with 'Counting' button, use this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```html
 <html>
        <head>
            <title>JSExample</title>
        </head>
    
        <body>
    
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function hello() {
                   alert("Hello there!");
          countClicks++;
                }
    
                var countClicks = 0;
    
                function upCount() { 
        alert(countClicks);
                }
    
            </script>
    
            <p><input type="button" name="button" value="Saying Hello" id="hello" onclick="hello();"/></p>
    
            <p><input type="button" name="click" value="Counting" id="click" onclick="upCount();"/></p>
    
        </body>
    
    </html>
```

If this is not what you meant, please let me know :)

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I want, Thanks a lot! It seems I wasn't calling the CountClicks variable inside with the 'Hello There' call

Answer (score 1):

The condition `if(document.getElementById('hello').onclick = "hello()") {` is not correct. I'm not sure what it should be doing, but know what it does: it assigns a string `hello()` to the `.onclick` callback of the `hello` element. As a `String` can't be executed (as opposed to a `Function`), it effectively removes the callback. You probably want something like this

```js
var countClicks = 0;

function hello() {
   alert("Hello there!");
   countClicks++;
}

function upCount() { 
    alert(countClicks);
}
```

```html
<p><input type="button" name="button" value="Saying Hello" id="hello" onclick="hello();"/></p>
<p><input type="button" name="click" value="Counting" id="click" onclick="upCount();"/></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(document.getElementById('hello').onclick == "hello()")
```

you've missed one =